Systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target shows different number of ordering cycles every time I run it
I am having some issues with booting up a fresh Ubuntu 24.04.1 from Intel Optane (which I just received from ebay): the boot process runs quickly but from time to time some systemd units don't run during the boot, the system comes up without the NetworkManager or something else like snapd-apparmor. The journalctl log reports that there are ordering cycles. Trying to find them, I noticed that systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target reports different things almost every time I run it:
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target 2>&1 | grep -i netwo | wc -l
7
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target 2>&1 | grep -i netwo | wc -l
13
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target 2>&1 | grep -i netwo | wc -l
0
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target 2>&1 | grep -i netwo | wc -l
0
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target 2>&1 | grep -i netwo | wc -l
18

Suspicious of the disk from ebay, I tried the same on the previously installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a Corsair NVMe, with the same results:
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target 2>&1 | grep -i netwo | wc -l
16
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target 2>&1 | grep -i netwo | wc -l
22
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target 2>&1 | grep -i netwo | wc -l
44
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target 2>&1 | grep -i netwo | wc -l
24
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target 2>&1 | grep -i netwo | wc -l
4
$ sudo systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target 2>&1 | grep -i netwo | wc -l
14

The boot process on the Corsair NVMe has similar issues with not starting some systemd units. But it is less frequent.
Why is this happening? Do I miss something about systemd-analyze verify? How come systemd-analyze verify can report different number of cycles every time you run it?
The versions. On Intel Optane:
$ systemd --version
systemd 255 (255.4-1ubuntu8.4)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT -GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY +P11KIT +QRENCODE +TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -BPF_FRAMEWORK -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=24.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=noble
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"

And the previous installation on Corsair NVMe (lspci actually reports it as Phison Electronics Corporation E12):
$ systemd --version
systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.12)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS"


Somehow it is caused by a custom mount unit. I don't know why. But, looking into the logs and what systemd-analyze verify printed, the unit seemed to show up in the sequence under every "found ordering cycle". So I disabled it, and added an automount unit to mount that custom directory after the user logs in. Now systemd-analyze verify multi-user.target never finds any problems. And the boot comes up fine.
The custom mount unit looks like this:
 [Unit]
Description=Mount BTRFS backup b filesystem
After=multi-user.target

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-label/backups_b
Where=/media/<user>/b
Type=btrfs
Options=defaults

LazyUnmount=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target 

I disabled it, and enabled the additional automount unit to trigger the mounting:
[Unit]
Description=Automount backup_b disk

[Automount]
Where=/media/<user>/b

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Now it works like a charm.
I don't see why that mount unit caused the ordering cycles. Any ideas what's up with that are welcome. But I am going to close this question since there are no comments or answers.
